# is it possible to subset list of custom class objects based on a parameter of these objects? (without LINQ)

Tags: c#, list, class, subset

What I am trying to achieve in C# without using LINQ is to subset a list of custom-class objects based on the value of one of the parameters of these objects.

Let's say the declaration of my list is the following:

```
List<MyCustom> listofobj = new List<MyCustom>();
```

Also, assume that the custom-class object "MyCustom" can return two parameters: MyCustom.name and MyCustom.age

Is there a way trough which I can retrieve and save into a temporary new list (let's call it "templist") the subset of the original list (i.e. "listofobj") formed by all its MyCustom objects that have "age" parameter greater than 30? Thanks!

Comment: Loop through the list, adding the elements satisfying the predicate to the new list. This is effectively the same as a where clause followed by a to list in method syntax. Linq would be more efficient and readable. Why not use it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So, first I apologize for not mentioning that I was meaning if there is something different from a brute-force loop trough all entries (my list has some thousands of lines). I will edit que question. Second, is there any source showing LINQ to be more efficient in terms of processing time than a for-loop? I've always found the opposite conclusion, although LINQ is certainly much more readable

Comment: @MAnd - Go for readable LINQ **unless** you have a demonstrable performance issue. Even then going with a `for` loop might only give a minor performance boost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get a subset of original list based on parameters without linq.

```
List<MyCustom> listofobj = new List<MyCustom>();
List<MyCustom> templist = new List<MyCustom>();

foreach(var obj in listofobj)
{
    if(obj.Age > 30)
    {
        templist.Add(obj); 
    }
}
```

You can also use this Linq.

```
templist = listofobj.Where(obj => obj.Age > 30).ToList();
```

Linq is slower than a normal code in general. but this should not be problem if this is not hot path in your code. performance difference is negligible.

Comment: _"Linq is slower than a normal code in general"_ -- LINQ _can_ be slower, especially if misused. But the LINQ implementation of the above won't be noticeably slower than the explicit implementation. It's doing practically the same thing.

Comment: it depends how you implement your code. anyway its one extra call with exact same implemention. but i agree with PeterDuniho. linq can slow part of your code if its misused.  @Hogan

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You can reinvent LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<MyCustom> WhereByAge(IEnumerable<MyCustom> source, int age)
{
    foreach (MyCustom myCustom in source)
    {
        if (myCustom.Age > age)
        {
            yield return myCustom;
        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
List<MyCustom> filteredList = new List(WhereByAge(listofobj, 30));
```

But why? I strongly recommend that if you want LINQ-like behavior, just use LINQ.